# Show an imageview instead of icon on toolbar options menu

Tags: android, kotlin, optionmenu

When you override the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` you get a options menu which opens when you click the 3 dot icon on top right. I want to show a circular image view with image of a user instead of the 3 dot icon. How do I do this?

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return true
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change three dots button on android to other button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267758/how-to-change-three-dots-button-on-android-to-other-button)

Comment: This link can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27692351/adding-icon-on-action-bar-instead-of-three-dots

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Amol you can learn more about the toolbar from [codepath guide](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-app-toolbar),

try to replace toolbar

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        </FrameLayout>


</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

if you just want to replace the icon and still keep overflow menu 
read from the similar answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267758/how-to-change-three-dots-button-on-android-to-other-button)